# How do you load an assembly in boo

Tags: .net, import, .net-assembly, boo

I'm trying to use the `.NET` assembly `Microsoft.VisualBasic` in my boo code that

looks like this:

```
import System

import Regex from System.Text.RegularExpressions

import Interaction from Microsoft.VisualBasic

import Microsoft.VisualBasic

## import Reflection.Assembly



## path="""C:\Windows\winsxs\msil_microsoft.visualbasic_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.1.7100.0_none_29f6b89369881fe4\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"""

## f=Reflection.Assembly.Load(Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(path).ToString())

## Interaction.Beep()

for i in Regex.Matches("def jam(this)","\\w+"):

    print i

arr=array(range(10))

print List(arr)

Array.Reverse(arr)

print List(arr)
```

When using `import Microsoft.VisualBasic` I get the error:

```
test.boo(9,1): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'Interaction'.
```

When using `import Interaction from Microsoft.VisualBasic`:

```
test.boo(4,8): BCE0167: Namespace 'Interaction' not found in assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic'
```

It still doesn't work when I try to load the dll this way:

```
Reflection.Assembly.Load(Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(path))
```

The thing is the above approach works in Powershell:

```
PS C:\mine> [reflection.assembly]::loadfile("C:\Windows\winsxs\msil_microsoft.visualbasic_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_6.1.7100.0_none_29f6b89369881fe4\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll")

GAC    Version        Location

---    -------        --------

True   v2.0.50727     C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

PS C:\mine> [microsoft.visualbasic.interaction]::beep()
```

I could also use `LoadWithPartialName` i.e `[Reflection.Assembly]::loadwithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')` but it's deprecated.

**How do I make this work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution, finally. Turns out the problem was the way I was compiling it. I was using `booc.exe test.boo`, instead of adding a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`. You don't even need to load it using `Reflection.Assembly`, you just import it, use it and compile with `booc.exe test.boo -r:Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`. Supplying a full path to the `dll` will also work. I guess `Powershell` and `boo` have different ways of accessing `.NET` assemblies.